# In Jenkins, how to build any branch created under a specific SVN repository URL?

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration

I need to setup a job that builds any copy of the trunk made to a specific SVN repository folder. Whenever someone *creates a new branch* in that specific folder, *that branch* should be checked out, built, and the tests run. Branches will accumulate in that specific folder and tests take quite a while (among others they employ external hardware), so it's not feasible to just build every branch found there every time a new one is added. Instead, the job will have to only built the branch that was newly added.

So what I need is this:

- monitor an URL (`an_svn_repo.com/path_to_project/some_branch_folder`) for changes
- if a new folder has been created under the URL (`an_svn_repo.com/path_to_project/some_branch_folder/new_stuff`) , check out *the new folder* (`some_branch_folder/new_stuff`, but not `some_branch_folder`)
- execute the build script in that folder

I have some ideas about how to approach that, but they are wildly different and I have no idea how feasible they are, so I'd like your input on this.

One way would be to check which sub-folder has the most recent changes and call the build script in that one. (But what if two branches are created at nearly the same time?) Another could be to store some information somewhere about what branches have been built and only build new ones. (But I have no idea whether Jenkins or a plugin has any means to store information between job invocations.) Also, a successful build of a branch could set a revision property on that branch, which Jenkins might then be able to ignore. Or I employ build parameters and start the job from a script.

I could just keep a script under `an_svn_repo.com/path_to_project/some_branch_folder` which does the necessary work, but it seems better to do most of the work in Jenkins itself, if possible.

What's your ideas?

Comment: "Or I employ build parameters and start the job from a script" ... yes

Comment: @Cole But then I'd forgo Jenkins' automation and users would have to manually start builds. I'd rather not do that.

Comment: There isn't any way to do this with plugins if that's what you are expecting, it would take some heavy scripting work as you mentioned. But if you figured out how to identify a newly created branch in a post-commit hook and use that to call the build job with the folder name as a parameter, I wouldn't think your jobs would have to be manually triggered. But it might be a lot better use of your time to reassess why you are branching so often that this would be necessary? Jenkins is pretty limited by your development process, and what is described here by definition is not continuous integration

Comment: I could script most of what's needed and call the script from Jenkins. Revision properties would allow to store the necessary information between job innovations. Only I'd rather do most of that in Jenkins instead of scripts. (As to why this is necessary: Basically, these are release candidates to be tested. The task is to make it as easy as possible to create such a candidate at the push of a button.)

Comment: Yes, I completely understand you have a legitimate problem that needs to be solved. The reason why this needs to be scripted rather than handled completely by jenkins is because you are trying to get jenkins to do something it was not designed for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611365/handling-multiple-branches-in-continuous-integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Build with Parameters](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+With+Parameters+Plugin) plugin. I've used that before to do something like this. We had a site that insisted that each feature and bug fix had to be a different branch, so we defined a *branch build* that used the *Build with Parameters* plugin to specify the branch to build.

All you have to do is define a Subversion post-commit hook that fires off the build for the project when a branch it is on is created or modified. It's a fairly straight forward trigger.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this (`+1`). Unfortunately, we have the hardest time to convince the admins to let us change revision properties, which we want to use in the script we're now implementing in order to mark branches that were already built. Making them allow us a post-commit hook (and changing this when necessary) is not something I want to fight for. `:(`

Comment: The solution we found is pretty similar to yours: We have a job that watches on the branches folder. On change it runs a script which checks whether there are branches that were not built previously and triggers another job with the right parameters (employing `/buildWithParameters?BRANCH=new_stuff`), which then builds and tests the branch. Branches that were built are marked by a property so that the script won't attempt to build them again. (Assuming that changing revision properties doesn't trigger Jenkins we want this to be a custom revision property, hence the fight with the admins.)

Comment: We're not proud on this solution, but it seems to work and do what we want.

Comment: Interesting using a job that watches the branch folder for changes. It should work almost the same as a post-commit trigger. Why don't you want to rebuild a branch that has been changed?

Comment: As I wrote in my question: "Branches will accumulate in that specific folder and tests take quite a while (among others they employ external hardware), so it's not feasible to just build every branch found there every time a new one is added."

Comment: I was thinking is that you could use `svn log -r$SVNREVISION -v` to find the name of the branch that was updated in the revision that fired the build, and then use _Build with Parameters_ to build only that branch.

Comment: We considered this, but, if triggered from Jenkins' scheduler rather than from a post-commit hook, there might be more than one check-in for one build, only the last of which would then be built. Our current approach doesn't have this shortcoming.